# SQL Server 2008 and sqljdbc4 JDK1.6 Connectivity

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

Has anyone successfully used SQL Server 2008 sqljdbc4.jar with JDK 1.6? The symptom is that it hangs on DriverManager.getConnection(url) statement with no exceptions or errors. Any hint would be appreciated.

I have successfully compiled and run the same code using sqljdbc.jar with JDK 1.5 on the same SQL Server 2008 database with no problems, so I don't think it's an application problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.

sqljdbc4.jar is incompatible with the latest java 6 (1.6.0 Update 29 (?) as of 11/2/2011). Everything works with (at least) 1.6.0 Update 25.

Answer (score 0):

sqljdbc4.jar is not compatible with jdk1.6 with update 29. I guess problem is there with this version of jdk. The same code wil work fine with other updates of jdk1.6